# Draw horizontal line on chart in chart.js on v2

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

I have drawn a line chart using chart.js. For the labels and datasets i am getting values from the database. I am new to chart.js and its very powerful library, yet i am unable to completely understand it. I want to draw multiples horizontal lines. Like where if mean of dataset, standard deviation and min and max. I have tried the question here in stackoverflow but these are giving errors or may be i am not able to understand the working. This is my chart.js code

```
function display_graph(id, label, data) {
var ctx = document.getElementById(id);
var data = {
    labels: data.labels,
    datasets: [
        {
            label: label,
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0.1,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
            borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            borderCapStyle: 'butt',
            borderDash: [],
            borderDashOffset: 0.0,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
            pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            pointBorderWidth: 1,
            pointHoverRadius: 5,
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
            pointRadius: 1,
            pointHitRadius: 10,
            data: data.assay_value,
            spanGaps: false
        }
    ]
};

//options
var options = {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
        display: true,
        position: "top",
        text: label,
        fontSize: 18,
        fontColor: "#111"
    },
    legend: {
        display: true,
        position: "bottom",
        labels: {
            fontColor: "#333",
            fontSize: 16
        }
    }
};
var Blanks_Chart=null;
Blanks_Chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: options
});}
```

Comment: Could someone please empty the edit queue?

Comment: Improved question: I have drawn a line chart using chart.js. For the labels and datasets I am getting values from a database. 

I want to draw multiples horizontal lines, for mean, standard deviation, min and max of the dataset. 

I have tried solutions of other question here on StackOverflow, but those are giving errors (or I am not able to understand them properly ).

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You could use the [chart.js annotation plugin](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation) to easily draw lines on your chart without having to mess with rendering pixels in your canvas manually (the old approach that is giving you errors).  Note, the plugin is created/supported by the same team as chart.js and is mentioned in the [chart.js docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#notes-popular-plugins).

Here is an [example codepen](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/qrXJLW) demonstrating creating a line on a chart.

Once you add the plugin, you simply just set `annotation` properties in your chart config.  Here is an example.

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["January", "February"],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
      borderWidth: 2,
      fill: false,
      data: [2, 10]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Chart.js Draw Line On Chart'
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: true
    },
    annotation: {
      annotations: [{
        type: 'line',
        mode: 'horizontal',
        scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
        value: 5,
        borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
        borderWidth: 4,
        label: {
          enabled: false,
          content: 'Test label'
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  Can you describe what is happening?  It could be a simple issue of chart.js versioning.  This solution targets chart.js v2.3.0 (the latest version at the time the question was answered), however some options and APIs have changed in the latest version (v2.7.1).

Comment: Now Resolved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47655173/chart-js-v2-draw-horizontal-baraverage-over-vertical-bar/47752998#47752998. Thanks Jordan !

Comment: The linked example on codepen does not draw the horizontal line.

Answer (score 7):

if you want to draw threshold line,easiest way is that using mixed line chart.

Note: Make an array filled with threshold value and the length should be same as your dataset.

```
var datasets = [1, 2, 3];
var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
var thresholdValue = 2;
var thresholdHighArray = new Array(datasets.length).fill(thresholdValue);
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: [],
                datasets: [
                {datasets}, thresholdHighArray]
            },         
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                legend: {
                    position: 'bottom',
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: 'Readings'
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: 'Reading ( °C )'
                        }
                    }]
                },
                annotation: {
                  annotations: [
                    {
                      type: "line",
                      mode: "vertical",
                      scaleID: "x-axis-0",
                      borderColor: "red",
                      label: {
                        content: "",
                        enabled: true,
                        position: "top"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are using the **NPM** package [chartjs-plugin-annotation.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-annotation), the important thing - which you may forget, is to **register** the plugin.

So first of all you installed the npm packages (here for **React**):

```
npm i react-chartjs-2                (depends on your framework)
npm i chartjs-plugin-annotation      (always required)
```

See [Vue.js](https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#introduction) or [Angular](https://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) for their framework depending packages.

**Option 1: Global plugin registration**

```
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import Chart from 'chart.js';
import * as ChartAnnotation from 'chartjs-plugin-annotation';

Chart.plugins.register([ChartAnnotation]); // Global

// ...
render() {
    return (
        <Line data={chartData} options={chartOpts} />
    )
}
```

**Option 2: Per chart plugin registration**

```
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import * as ChartAnnotation from 'chartjs-plugin-annotation';

// ...
render() {
    return (
                                                   {/* per chart */}
        <Line data={chartData} options={chartOpts} plugins={[ChartAnnotation]} />
    )
}
```

`chartData` is equivalent to the `data: {` section and `chartOpts` to `options: {` from jordanwillis [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42799913/4300087). See [this](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation/issues/156#issuecomment-572119492) github post for further information.

There are many other [plugins available](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.7.2/notes/extensions.html) for chart.js.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of getting it working in a Rails view if you're using it with the Chartkick gem:

```
<%=
  line_chart profit_per_day_chart_path(staff), xtitle: 'Day', ytitle: 'Profit',
    library: {
      annotation: {
        annotations: [
          {
            type: 'line',
            mode: 'horizontal',
            scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
            value: 20,
            label: {
              content: 'My Horizontal Line',
              enabled: true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
%>
```

Ensure that you've registered the chartjs-plugin-annotation.js plugin with Chart.js first:

```
import ChartAnnotationsPlugin from 'chartjs-plugin-annotation';
Chart.plugins.register(ChartAnnotationsPlugin);
```