# Chart Js V2 draw Horizontal Bar(Average) Over Vertical Bar

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, chart.js, bar-chart

I want to draw a single bar over vertical bars(Green Bar).  I am using Chart JS V2 with  Angular 4.

[image]

I found some code to draw lines but its not working in Angular 4.

I used also tried using `annotation` but its not working. 
Command to add annotation: **npm install chartjs-plugin-annotation --save**

Below is my code, works fine to draw vertical bars only. Can anyone help me to draw horizontal line over it.

**Answer**:

Install `npm install chartjs-plugin-annotation --save`

Then `import 'chartjs-plugin-annotation'`;

```
this.ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    this.myChart = new Chart(this.ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: this.barData.getLabels(),
            datasets: [{
                label: this.barData.actualLegendLabel,
                data: this.barData.getLineData(),
                backgroundColor: this.backgroundColorBarOne,
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(81,117, 194,1)',
                ]}]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                responsive: true,
                scaleBeginAtZero: false,
                barBeginAtOrigin: true,
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false
                    }
                }],
                xAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false
                    }
                }]
            },
            legend: {
                cursor: "line",
                position: 'top',
                labels: {
                    fontSize: 10,                       
                }
            },
            layout: {
                padding: {
                    left: 3,
                    right: 3,
                    top: 5,
                    bottom: 5
                }
            }, annotation: {
                annotations: [{
                    drawTime: 'afterDraw', // overrides annotation.drawTime if set
                    id: 'a-line-1', // optional
                    type: 'line',
                    mode: 'horizontal',
                    scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
                    value: '25',
                    borderColor: 'red',
                    borderWidth: 2,           
                    // Fires when the user clicks this annotation on the chart
                    // (be sure to enable the event in the events array below).
                    onClick: function(e) {
                        // `this` is bound to the annotation element
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where exactly should the green bar be located on the y-axis?

Comment: @maxpaj As a average value it can be anywhere.

Comment: With chart.js you can use layers and draw multiple charts together, you want to place a line chart on top of you bar chart. Check this out: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/mixed.html

Comment: This helped me a lot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51664741/chartjs-plugin-annotations-not-displayed-in-angular-5

Answer (score 4):

You can add a plugin to your chart which can draw anything you'd like on the chart, for example a green line. You can read about plugins in [the documentation for ChartJS](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugins). Since you want the green line to appear above the vertical bars, you should use the `afterDraw` method.

Once you've set the plugin up, the steps to accomplish this would be:

1. Calculate the mean of all the bars in your chart (sum them up and divide by the number of bars)
2. From the previous calculation: Decide the Y position of the line and based on that, draw the green line on the canvas.

Check out [CanvasRenderingContext2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D) if you are new to how the browser canvas works.