# chartjs-plugin-annotations not displayed in angular 5

Tags: angular5, chart.js

While using the chart.js and the plugin chartjs-plugin-annotation, annotations are not showing while using angular 5, no error messages are displayed.

I have created a cut down example of code that exhibits the problem

console.log(Chart.plugins) shows the plugin looks to be registered as plugin[3] however it doesn't have an id as the inbuilt ones do, is this a problem?

[image]

chart.component.ts

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
import 'chartjs-plugin-annotation';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chart-component',
  templateUrl: './chart.component.html'
})
export class ChartComponent {
  public currentCount = 0;

  chart : Chart ; // This will hold our chart info

  simpleChart() {

    console.log(Chart.plugins);

    this.chart = new Chart('canvas', {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: ['0','1','2', '3','4'],
        datasets: [
          {
            data: [0,1,2,5,4,5],
            borderColor: "#3cba9f",
            fill: false,
          },

        ]
      },
      options: {
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            display: true
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            display: true,
            id: 'y-axis-0'
          },
          ]
        },
        plugins: {
          annotation: {
            annotations: [{
              type: 'line',
              id: 'hLine',
              mode: 'horizontal',
              scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
              value: 2.5,  // data-value at which the line is drawn
              borderWidth: 2.5,
              borderColor: 'black'
            }]
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.simpleChart();
  }
}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had some fun trying to get annotations working - in case you haven't already solved it, try this...

Change your imports statement to:

```
import * as ChartAnnotation from 'chartjs-plugin-annotation';
```

Change `ngOnInit()` to:

```
ngOnInit() {
  let namedChartAnnotation = ChartAnnotation;
  namedChartAnnotation["id"]="annotation";
  Chart.pluginService.register( namedChartAnnotation);
  this.simpleChart();
}
```

Lastly, I believe the annotation object is supposed to be a child of options, not plugins. Mine looks like this:

```
"options": {
    "legend": {
        "display": true
    },
    "scales": {
        "xAxes": [{
                "display": true
            }
        ],
        "yAxes": [{
                "display": true,
                "ticks": {
                    "min": 0,
                    "max": 40
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "tooltips": {
        "enabled": true,
        "backgroundColor": "#eee",
        "titleFontColor": "#000"
    },
    "annotation": {
        "annotations": [{
                "type": "box",
                "xScaleID": "x-axis-0",
                "yScaleID": "y-axis-0",
                "yMin": 0,
                "yMax": 15,
                "xMin": 864,
                "xMax": 1285,
                "borderWidth": 1,
                "backgroundColor": "rgba(200,60,60,0.25)",
                "borderColor": "rgba(200,60,60,0.25)"
            }, {
                "type": "box",
                "xScaleID": "x-axis-0",
                "yScaleID": "y-axis-0",
                "yMin": 30,
                "yMax": 40,
                "xMin": 864,
                "xMax": 1285,
                "borderWidth": 1,
                "backgroundColor": "rgba(60,60,200,0.25)",
                "borderColor": "rgba(60,60,200,0.25)"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Makes for a pretty graph :)

[image: Image of graph produced with above options]

(except I got the colours bass ackwards! Oops!)

Comment: I can see why I couldn't figure this out, the typescript type definition is not correct. setting options.annotations = { ... } doesn't compile - the type definitions point to using options.plugins.annotations, which compiles but doesn't work.

Comment: Works for me, Great solution

Answer (score 7):

As an adition of what Ade said. You can also add the plugin this way

```js
import { ChartOptions } from 'chart.js';
import * as ChartAnnotation from 'chartjs-plugin-annotation';

this.chart = new Chart('canvas', {
  ...
  options: {
    ...
    annotation: { ... }
  } as ChartOptions,
  plugins: [ChartAnnotation]
});
```

Adding the `{...} as ChartOptions` makes that TypeScript doesn't complain

Comment: Got it without having to add the `ngOnInit` from @ade

Answer (score 4):

To anyone having a TypeScript error saying that annotation isn't a ChartOptions property. After looking for an answer for a week or two I found a way to fix the issue.

Follow this path: node_modules/@types/chart.js/index.d.ts

Open index.d.ts, locate interface ChartOptions {
and add this line.
annotation?: Object;
}

This is how I fixed my issue after every other solution failed.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem recently, I fixed it by registerPlugin under constructor.

Here is my solution:

1. import the plugin to your component:

```
import * as annotations from 'chartjs-plugin-annotation';
```

2. add this line to your constructor:

```
constructor(...) { BaseChartDirective.registerPlugin(annotations);}
```

3. If you are using typescript you may need to extend the ChartOptions interface with annotation:

```
interface CustomizeChartOptions extends ChartOptions {
    annotation?: any
}
```

4. config your chartOptions with annotation

```js
public barChartOptions: CustomizeChartOptions = {
        // your other ChartOptions setting here
        annotation: {
            annotations: [
                {
                    drawTime: "afterDatasetsDraw",
                    type: 'line',
                    mode: 'vertical',
                    scaleID: 'x-axis-0',
                    value: '1 Dec',
                    borderColor: 'red',
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    label: {
                        content: 'CURRENT',
                        enabled: true,
                        position: 'top'
                    }
                }
            ]
        }

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late, but, as of now (ng2-charts 3.0.11), these answers are not working as the API changed. The annotation configuration must now be in plug-ins.
The annotation plug-in must be registered before being used.
Here is what i found, from the examples:
in app.module.ts:

```
import { NgChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
import { default as Annotation } from 'chartjs-plugin-annotation'

// ...
imports: [
  //...
  NgChartsModule.forRoot({
    defaults: {},
    plugins: [ Annotation ]
  }),
  // ...
```

and then, in your component.ts file:

```
  chartOptions: ChartConfiguration['options'] = {
  scales: {
    // ...
  },
  plugins: {
    annotation: {
      annotations: [
        {
          type: 'line',
          scaleID: 'y',
          value: 16,
          borderColor: 'green',
          borderWidth: 6
        },
      ]
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).