# How to add avarage line in chart js in nextjs project

Tags: javascript, next.js, chart.js

I'm developing a chart using chart.js in nextjs project. i won't able to find a way to add average line using "annotation". is there any way to do that in nextjs.

**this is how i import the chart js components.**

```
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  BarElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from 'chart.js';
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';

ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  BarElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
);
```

**this is how i configure the options**

```
export const options = {
  plugins: {
    tooltip: {
      callbacks: {
        title: (context: any) => {
          return context[0].label
        }
      }
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Egg Burn',
    },
  },
  responsive: true,
  scales: {
    x: {
      stacked: false,
      grid: {
        display: false
      },
      callback: function (value: any, index: any, ticks: any) {
        return '$' + value;
      },
    },
    y: {
      stacked: false,
      grid: {
        display: false
      }
    },
  },
  
};
```

**this is the component**

```
<Bar options={options} data={data} />
```

Comment: This link may helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42691873/draw-horizontal-line-on-chart-in-chart-js-on-v2

Comment: Why can you not use the [annotation plugin](https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/1.2.0/samples/line/average.html)?

Comment: thnaks D. Nguyen