# Change horizontal line length - Annotation Chart js in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, chart.js, bar-chart

I'm trying to add horizontal line as target for each bar in bar chart using chart.js in angular.

My Code here,

```
this.chart = new Chart("canvas", {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "# of Votes",
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)",
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },      
  options: {
    plugins:pluginAnnotations,
    annotation: {
      annotations: [
        {
          type: "line",
          mode: "horizontal",
          scaleID: "y-axis-0",
          value: 8.19,
          borderColor: "#222222",
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderDash: [5,5],
          label: {
            enabled: true,
            fontColor: "#000000",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
            position: "right",
            fontSize: 13,
            yAdjust: -10
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

> I'm using this following version of resources
>
> 1. chartjs-plugin-annotation@0.5.7
> 2. chart.js@2.9.4

My Expected output(with dotted line):

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: You can try following this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42799913/15291557

Comment: Hi @D.Betsov, Please refer my expected output picture. I need horizontal line on each bar separately.